# How to convert a number into unit256 number?

Tags: solidity

I want to convert 11 into unit256 equivalent.

How this can be done? Is there any online converter?

Comment: any number is a `uint256`, by default, in Solidity. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert 11 to uint256, because 11 is already uint256 type.

Maybe you are having problems because of ether units, here you can test how it works https://eth-converter.com/ take a look at Eth, Gwei and Wei conversions

1eth = 1000000000 Gwei = 1000000000000000000 Wei

Hope it helps